# Figuring out some programming problems in C# (homework)

Tags: c#

```
{

class AutoPolicy
{
    public int AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string MakeAndModel { get; set; }
    private string state;
    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set {
            if (State.Equals("MA" || "CT" || "ME" || "NH" || "NJ" || "NY" || "PA" || "VT")
            {
                State = state;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The state code is wrong.");
            }
        }
    }


    public AutoPolicy(int accountNumber, string makeAndModel, string state)
    {
        AccountNumber = accountNumber;
        MakeAndModel = makeAndModel;
        State = state;
    }

    public bool IsNoFaultState
    {
        get
        {
            bool noFaultState;
            switch (State)
            {
                case "MA":
                case "NJ":
                case "NY":
                case "PA":
                    noFaultState = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    noFaultState = false;
                    break;
            }
            return noFaultState;
        }
    }



    class AutoPolicyTest
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            AutoPolicy policy1 = new AutoPolicy(11111111, "Toyota Camry", "NJ");
            AutoPolicy policy2 = new AutoPolicy(22222222, "Ford Fusion", "ME");

            PolicyInNoFaultState(policy1);
            PolicyInNoFaultState(policy2);
        }
        public static void PolicyInNoFaultState(AutoPolicy policy)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The auto policy:");
            Console.Write($"Account #: {policy.AccountNumber};");
            Console.WriteLine($"Car: {policy.MakeAndModel};");
            Console.Write($"State {policy.State};");
            Console.Write($"{(policy.IsNoFaultState ? "is" : "is not")}");
            Console.WriteLine(" a no-fault state\n");
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is my code for an homework assignment I have to modify a program in the book (Which I'd much rather make my own program), but the instructions say: Modify the program to validate the two letter state codes for the northeast states. It then lists the different states and the corresponding codes, all of which are in my code. Then it says: In the State property's set accessor, use the logical OR (||) operator to create a compound condition in an if...else statement that compares the method's argument with each two-letter code.

I apologize for the huge block of code but I'm not sure what's causing the problem (I'm kind of new to c#), but the error I'm getting: is operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'. Any help would be appreciated, as this makes little sense to me, as being new to language. Thanks!

Comment: _if (State.Equals("MA") || State.Equals(.....) || State.Equals(....)_ and so on

Comment: “I'm not sure what's causing the problem” means you have to learn [how to debug](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You can also do something like: `string[] validStates = { "MA", "CT", "ME", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "PA", "VT" }; if (validStates.Any(vs => State.Equals(vs)) { State = state; }`

Comment: @DourHighArch you are not at all wrong

Answer (score 1):

An expression in the form

```
"MA" || "CT"
```

does not extend to a series of comparisons against the `State` variable, as you seem to have expected. Instead, it attempts to apply a logical OR to two strings, which is an operation not defined in C#, therefore the compilation error.

If you want to go for a shorter solution, you could write this:

```
if(new List<string> { "MA", "CT", "ME" }.Contains(value)) 
{
    /* ... */
}
```

It constructs a list of string and then tests if the string that is assigned to your property is an element of that list.

Also, in your current code you are incorrectly referring to the property `State` inside its setter, which will cause a stack overflow at runtime. That assignment should be `state = value` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Close, but should be this:

```
if (State.Equals("MA") || State.Equals("CT") || State.Equals("ME") || State.Equals("NH") || State.Equals("NJ") || State.Equals("NY") || State.Equals("PA") || State.Equals("VT"))
{
    State = state;
}
```